# Microsoft.Fakes Error 106

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll, dllimport, microsoft-fakes

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ulitmate and trying to "Add Fakes Assembly" to a test project. The initial build gives me this error:

> Error  106 Assembly 'Core.Fakes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the build server matches the same update level as your build environment.  I had this problem, and it was resolved by making sure that I was at Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate update 4.  On my build server it was Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate update 1.  Upgrading to update 4 fixed the problem.  Make sure though that you completely uninstall update 1 first.